# why (unsigned int) produces negative numbers in the output in C

Tags: c, unsigned-integer

i find the output always carries a negative sign in the code below, although i indicated that the bits for the variable `x` are for unsigned integers in the initiation statement.

why `~x` produces a negatively signed number while there is no bit assigned for the sign of the number to be reflected in the first place?

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main() {
    unsigned int x = 11;
    printf("not x=%d", ~x);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's about the interpretation that printf gives to the parameter you pass.

```
unsigned int x = 11;
printf("not x=%d", ~x);
```

During the function call the *default argument promotions* will pass ~x to printf as type unsigned int.  The default argument promotions are applied due to va_args from the signature of printf.

Also, *integer promotions* are applied for computing the ~x -- from `6.5.3.3 Unary arithmetic operators:`

> The result of the ~ operator is the bitwise complement of its
>   (promoted) operand (that is, each bit in the result is set if and only
>   if the corresponding bit in the converted operand is not set). The
>   integer promotions are performed on the operand, and the result has
>   the promoted type. If the promoted type is an unsigned type, the
>   expression ~E is equivalent to the maximum value representable in that
>   type minus E.

So you pass an unsigned integer, but *printf will cast it to int*, as %d expects to find an int.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is dependent on the platform, but the basic answer is that `printf` doesn't know that the thing you're passing was declared as unsigned. It's just a value. if you use the `%d` format, that value will be interpreted as a signed integer. If you use `%u`, it will be interpreted as unsigned. On a processor using two's complement representation, a value with the most significant bit set is negative. Since `~11` has that bit set, it is shown as a negative number.

Comment: The behaviour is *not* implementation-defined, it is *undefined* by 7.21.6.1.p9.

Comment: @Andy Schweig u r saying that the representation of the bits changed the result and that was changed by indicating different output formulas (%d,%u)? please correct me if i am wrong ..